# Asp.net core 2.2 API error the request matched multiple endpoints

Tags: api, asp.net-core, routes

I have API controller like this :

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ImageCourseController : ControllerBase
{
    #region Ctor
    private readonly GenericRepository<ImageCourse> _imageCourseGOP;
    public ImageCourseController(GenericRepository<ImageCourse> imageCourseGOP)
    {
        _imageCourseGOP = imageCourseGOP;
    }
    #endregion

    [HttpGet("/api/ImageCourse")]
    public async Task<ImageCourse> Get([FromQuery] int id)
    {
        return await _imageCourseGOP.ReadAsync(id);
    }

    [HttpGet("/api/ImageCourse")]
    public async Task<List<ImageCourse>> GetByCourseId([FromQuery] int courseId)
    {
        return await _imageCourseGOP.SelectAsync(n => n.CourseId == courseId);
    }
    ...
}
```

Therefore method Get route is "api/imagecourse?id=1" and method GetByCourseId route is "api/imagecourse?courseId=3".
My question is:
why am I getting this error even though I have different routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to match the request to expected endpoint based on the querystring, you can try to implement a custom [`ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionconstraints.actionmethodselectorattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to enable or disable action for a given request based on the querystring.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CheckQueryStingAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public string QueryStingName { get; set; }
    public bool CanPass { get; set; }
    public CheckQueryStingAttribute(string qname, bool canpass)
    {
        QueryStingName = qname;
        CanPass = canpass;
    }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
    {
        StringValues value;

        routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue(QueryStingName, out value);

        if (CanPass)
        {
            return !StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
        }

        return StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    }
}
```

Apply to action methods

```
[HttpGet("/api/ImageCourse")]
[CheckQuerySting("id", true)]
[CheckQuerySting("courseId", false)]
public async Task<ImageCourse> Get([FromQuery] int id)
{
    return await _imageCourseGOP.ReadAsync(id);
}

[HttpGet("/api/ImageCourse")]
[CheckQuerySting("courseId", true)]
[CheckQuerySting("id", false)]
public async Task<List<ImageCourse>> GetByCourseId([FromQuery] int courseId)
{
    return await _imageCourseGOP.SelectAsync(n => n.CourseId == courseId);
}
```

Besides, you can refer to [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/defining-asp-net-core-controller-action-constraint-to-match-the-correct-action/) that explained how to define ASP.NET Core Controller action constraint to match the correct action.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer is more specialized

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you have two actions with the same route.

```
[HttpGet("/api/ImageCourse")]
```

Using `[FromQuery]` doesn't make the route different, it just tells it where to look for that parameter.

Here's one alternative action to replace your two actions:

```
[HttpGet("/api/ImageCourse")]
public async Task<object> Get([FromQuery] int? id, [FromQuery] int? courseId)
{
    object result;

    if(id.HasValue)
        result = await _imageCourseGOP.ReadAsync(id.Value);
    else if(courseId.HasValue)
        result = await _imageCourseGOP.SelectAsync(n => n.CourseId == courseId.Value);
    else
        result = null;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.@Fei Han answer is more specialized